# How to compare key and value in multiple array?

Tags: php

I have to compare dropdown with multiple array, my first array is

```
 [menu_master] => Array
(
    [master/city] => City
    [master/national_holiday] => National Holiday
    [master/operator_comments] => Operator Comments
    [master/sensors] => Sensors
    [master/modbus] => Modbus
    [master/manufacturers] => Manufacturers
    [master/make_model] => Make Model
)
```

my second array is

```
 [role_assign] => Array
(
    [1] => View
    [2] => Write
)
```

And my third array is come form database

```
    [database_fetch] => Array
        (
            [master/city] => 1
            [master/national_holiday] => 2
            [master/operator_comments] => 1
            [master/sensors] => 2
            [master/modbus] => 1
            [master/manufacturers] => 2
            [master/make_model] => 1
)
```

Now these array apply to below code. 
I want show selected option of dropdown which comes form database fetch array.

```
<?php
                    $menu_manster =  menu_master();
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($menu_manster as $k => $val) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                      <td class="mailbox-name">{{ $val }}</td>
                      <td><?php $roles_assign =  roles_assign_id(); ?>
                            <select class="form-control master-menu" name="master_menu[{{$k}}]">
                              <option value="">Select Role</option>
                                <?php 

                                    foreach ($roles_assign as $key => $value) { 
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
                              <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++;  } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `$roles_assign` loop, you have to check whether the `$value` matches with the value of the `database_fetch` item. Assuming you have stored the database_fetch data in a variable named `$database_fetch`, the solution would look something like this:

```
<?php
$menu_manster =  menu_master();
$i = 1;
foreach($menu_manster as $k => $val) {
?>
<tr>
  <td>{{ $i }}</td>
  <td class="mailbox-name">{{ $val }}</td>
  <td><?php $roles_assign =  roles_assign_id(); ?>
        <select class="form-control master-menu" name="master_menu[{{$k}}]">
          <option value="">Select Role</option>
            <?php 

                foreach ($roles_assign as $key => $value) { 
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"<?=($database_fetch[$k] === $key ? ' selected' : '')?>><?php echo $value; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php $i++;  } ?>
```

Comment: how to check with database_fetch array, as it is alerady in array

Comment: i have little confusion as why are you check with first menu_master array?